# Como obter o objeto com o foco no Android

Tags: android, view, edittext, listener

Ola a todos Eu tenho o seguinte Listener a baixo que verifica se um editText foi alterado, o Listener será idêntico para vários editText então eu gostaria de obter o editText atual através da propriedade "v", para evitar a repetição de código e criar apenas um "onFocusChangeListener" e atribuir a vários editText.

```
        edtDescPer.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            executeOnChange = false;
            v.focus

            if (hasFocus) {
                sTemp = edtDescPer.getText().toString();
                edtDescPer.setText("");
            } else {
                if (edtDescPer.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    edtDescPer.setText(sTemp);
            }

            executeOnChange = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode obter o elemento obtendo o id da view, através do método `getId()` , por exemplo

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

 switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editText1:
        //caso for o editText1
        break;
    case R.id.editText2:
        //caso for o editText2
        break;
    }
}
```

Crie o `OnFocusChangeListener`, separado, não já como parâmetro do edittext, por exemplo:

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener exemplo = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                 switch (v.getId()) {
                      case R.id.editText1:
                         //caso for o editText1
                         break;
                      case R.id.editText2:
                        //caso for o editText2
                         break;
                      }
            }
        } ;
```

e depois só atribuir ao edittext

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(exemplo);
editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(exemplo);
```

Comment: Marco a sua sugestão foi fundamental para resolver meu problema. Vou por o código de como ficou a minha função em um resposta, mas vou marcar a sua como como correta

Answer (score 1):

Segue a baixo a declaração da função onFocusChangeListener feita com a dica do Marco Giovanni:

```
    View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        executeOnChange = false;
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(v.getId());

        if (hasFocus) {
            sTemp = et.getText().toString();
            et.setText("");
        } else {
            if (et.getText().toString().equals(""))
                et.setText(sTemp);
        }

        executeOnChange = true;
    }
} ;
```

Atribuição da função no onCreate:

```
edtDescPer.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
```

Comment: Você não precisa fazer um `findViewById(v.getId())`, basta fazer um cast na `view` que você recebe como parâmetro, `EditText et = (EditText)v`

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer com que sua classe implemente o **OnFocusChangeListener**, dessa forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    private EditText editText1, editText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        String liganame = editText1.getText().toString();
        String liganame2 = editText2.getText().toString();

        if(liganame.length() == 0) {
            if(editText1.requestFocus()) {
                //primeiro
            }
        }

        if(liganame2.length() == 0) {
            if(editText2.requestFocus()) {
                //segundo
            }
        }

    }
}
```